# Why it doesn't show me the greatest common divison?

Tags: c++

When i try to start the program it doesn't work and doesn't show me any error. Why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned a,b;
    cout<<"a=";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"b=";
    cin>>b;
    {
        while(a!=b)
        {
            if(a>b)
                (a==a-b);
            else
                (b==b-a);
        }
    }
    cout<<"cmmdc=",a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never modify `a` or `b` so unless they start out as the same value you get an infinite loop.

Comment: I would suggest read a good C++ book or take a look at the C++ documentation

Comment: Thank you for posting the entire source code. *It doesn't work* is not a useful description of a problem. In this case you should have written: ``It compiles cleanly with `g++ -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror`, and after typing `5` and `6` to its input, it keeps hanging while using 100% CPU.''. What was missing for your description: how you compiled it, what the compiler printed, what input you gave it, and what the program was doing after not printing anything.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `a==a-b` with `a=a-b`.

Replace `b==b-a` with `b=b-a`.

The operator `==` is comparison, it doesn't modify its arguments. The operator `=` is assignment, it modifies its left argument to the value of its right argument.

Replace `cout<<"cmmdc=",a` with `cout<<"cmmdc="<<a`, otherwise `a` won't be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Even after changing the `==`s to `=`s, you'll get an infinite loop if any but not both of `a` and `b` is 0. To avoid that, use this loop instead:

```
while (b != 0) {
  const unsigned olda = a;
  a = b;
  b = olda % b;
}
// GCD is now in a.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the simplest way to find gcd of two numbers :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    cout<<"a = ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"b = ";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"GCD = " << __gcd(a,b);
}
```